# Cant connect to WebSocket Node.JS

Tags: node.js, websocket

i'm making a game that use WebSockets and this is the code that i use to  start a WebSocket server:

```
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const port = 3005;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
}); 

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ server })  
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {});
```

And this code i use for connecting a user to the WebSocket:

```
this.SERVER_URL ='ws://localhost/?fvukovic'; <-- fvukovic is the user
this.ws = new WebSocket(this.SERVER_URL, ["test"]);      
this.ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('open'); 
};
```

This works perfectly, but when i push that on server and i change the ip address to 195.201.119.221 which is the ip of the server, port is still 3005, i cant connect to it anymore..

I get this error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://195.201.119.221:3005/?fvukovic' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Do i need something more when i put the the app on a real server?

Comment: Did you checked if the port 3005 is opened ?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Make sure you have opened the port on your server. If you use nginx, make sure you've proxied it.

Comment: huh,
the port is free, 
but i'm not sure about the proxy.. and i'm not using nginx still..just installed node and started the server script..
Do u have some article or something that can help me?
Ty for fast response!